# Powershell: Find all SQL Server instances per ser server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Strictly speaking, the question is, I use this solution and it works, but is there a better way?

With the following caveats.

1) I don't want to do a network wide search for SQL instances, I am interrogating known SQL servers, but I want to grab the instance names on each.

2) The code assumes Microsoft will never change the display name for the SQL Server Service.

```
function getSQLInstance ([string]$SERVER) {
    $services = Get-Service -Computer $SERVER
    # Filter for SQL services
    $services = $services | ? DisplayName -like "SQL Server (*)"
    # Remove MSSQL$ qualifier to get instance name
    try {
        $instances = $services.Name | ForEach-Object {($_).Replace("MSSQL`$","")}
    }catch{
        # Error if none found
        return -1
    }
    return $instances
}

getSQLInstance "YOUR_SERVER"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, take a look at how [SQL Power Doc](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/) discovers instances on a server. Which, from looking at `NetworkScan.psm1`, appears to be very similar to your approach:

```
$ManagedComputer.Services | ForEach-Object {

                if (($_.Name).IndexOf('$') -gt 0) {
                    $InstanceName = ($_.Name).Substring(($_.Name).IndexOf('$') + 1)
                    $IsNamedInstance = $true
                    $ManagedComputerServerInstanceName = $InstanceName
                } else {
                    $InstanceName = $null
                    $IsNamedInstance = $false
                    $ManagedComputerServerInstanceName = $_.Name
                }
```

Or, just use SQL Power Doc and point it at specific server names to collect this and more data about the instances.